# I run multiple Queries in Big Query Problem facing in correct and structured output

Tags: google-bigquery

I run the query and get the output in answer Number. If I run the query in parts it will return 3 rows which is correct

```
WITH query AS 
(
   SELECT
       opt.answerNo AS ans,
       task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds AS time
   FROM
       Test_2019_02_07
   CROSS JOIN
       UNNEST(task.workflowInfo.answers) AS answer
   CROSS JOIN
       UNNEST(answer.options) AS opt
),
raw AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans  = 1 AND query.time BETWEEN 1550341800000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans1
    FROM
        query

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 2 AND query.time BETWEEN 1550341800000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans1 
    FROM
        query

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 3 AND query.time BETWEEN 1550341800000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans1
    FROM
        query 
),
raw1 AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 1 AND query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans2
    FROM
        query 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 2 AND query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans2
    FROM
        query 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 3 AND query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550341899999) AS ans2
    FROM
        query 
),
raw3 AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 1 AND query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550514699999) AS ans3
    FROM
        query 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans = 2 AND query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550514699999) AS ans3
    FROM
        query

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
        COUNTIF(query.ans  = 3 AND  query.time BETWEEN 1548959400000 AND 1550514699999) AS ans3
    FROM
        query 
)
SELECT * 
FROM raw, raw1, raw3
```

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM raw
```

it will return

```
0
0
0
```

While running

```
SELECT * FROM raw1
```

returns

```
1
1
3
```

and running

```
SELECT * FROM raw3
```

returns

```
3
1
1
```

But when I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM raw, raw1, raw3
```

it will return 27 rows with repeated numbers

I expect

```
ans1   ans2   ans3
-------------------
  0      1     3
  0      1     1 
  0      3     1
```

In this way I did not get why its returning me 27 rows.

When I run this

```
SELECT * 
FROM raw, raw1, raw3
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLiZS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

By default, if we add more tables in select query, it will do [cross join](https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-cross-join).

In your case to get the expected output we need to use joins. Because we don't have any common column, we can add the `ROW_NUMBER()` to all select queries and join with that column.

**Example:**

```
with
query1 as (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) as rn1, id as id1 from table1),
query2 as (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) as rn2, id as id2 from table2)

select * from query1 join query2 on query1.rn1=query2.rn2
```